# FCM how to display the push notification preview when receiving a message

Tags: android, flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging

I implemented the push notification on Android through Firebase, I have a problem that I haven't found an answer anywhere, I'm getting my push perfectly, but when I receive a notification with the application closed, the default sound is played, but the message does not slide on screen, if I go to the notifications my message is there, but it does not slide as soon as it arrives on the device is this a parameter of the firebase API or is it an implementation in the code? In the app's permissions, I'm allowed to slide messages. Has anyone come across this?

This is the body of the request for the legacy firebase api.

`POST - https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`

```
{
    "notification": {
        "body": "my body",
        "title":"my title",
        "sound": "default"
    },
    "data":{
        "click_action": "",
        "type": "",
        "action":"",
        "content":""
    },
    "priority": "high",
    "to": "token device"
}
```

Comment: Can you share us some logs?

Comment: Yes of course, just specify what you need.

Comment: Sorry, I mean, which kind of message are you sending from FCM? There are two types: notification and data-messages, can I see your json?

Comment: I updated with the body ta request. It is a data notification, but even if I remove the data from the notification body, I still cannot preview the message.

Comment: this is json that I'm using in a project for notification messages: `{"project_id":"project_id","notification":{"title":"Test Notification", "body":"Body"}, "to":"token"}` I think that `project_id` is optional

Comment: You have to handle data notifications on App side and create them You will have to create a NotificationChannel for that. Can you show us the code where you receive your notification? i.e the onMessageReceived() method?